# Why does "I ain't doing nothing" translate to "I am doing nothing"?

Tags: meaning, double-negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I ain’t got no money”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47527/i-aint-got-no-money)

Why does the phrase "I ain't doing nothing" mean "I am doing nothing"?

According to me, "I ain't doing nothing" should translate to "I am not doing nothing", which implies that "I am doing something".

Comment: 'Rules' are more flexible in English than some would like. This usage is idiomatic, and idioms (of which there are many) break rules – some, semantic rules (how can a camel be a ship?) and some, syntactic rules. Innit.

Comment: Because in natural language, double negatives are negative, not positive: language isn't math. Sophists will claim that _I ain't doing nothing_ = _I am doing something_, but they're just pretending to be nitpicking lawyers. Context will tell you when a double negative is intended to express a positive and when it's intended to express a negative. Words alone are not enough, especially when they're on a page instead of coming out of a speaker's mouth.

Comment: It's the same in French: [Non, je ne regrette rien](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/Je-Ne-Regrette-Rien-Je-Ne-Regrette-Rien.html) (Edith Piaf). /// Non, rien de rien // Non, je ne regrette rien [No, I don't regret nothing = No, I don't regret anything] // Ni le bien qu'on m'a fait // Ni le mal; tout ça m'est bien égal!

Comment: A camel can even be an aeroplane...

Comment: I ain't never done nothing to nobody

Comment: [You may find this page useful.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative)

Comment: @Arch: I looked at the Wikipedia page & disagree with what the author calls a "double negative": "In Standard English, two negatives are understood to resolve to a positive. This rule was observed as early as 1762, when Bishop Robert Lowth wrote _A Short Introduction to English Grammar with Critical Notes_. For instance, 'I do not disagree' could mean 'I certainly agree'." This is actually called "[litotes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litotes)": "understatement in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of the contrary (as in 'not a bad singer' or 'not unhappy')".

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many questions. In fact, compare the answer [you've got here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97524/300) to e.g. [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/47534/300). Duplication of effort at its worst. Please search the site before posting. (We have dedicated tags for pretty much everything, including double negation.) Thank you.

Comment: @BillFranke Yeah, the term "litote" is certainly a better term to describe such scenario. And the usage of litote can even be found in Bible so I don't see the point mentioning Bishop Robert Lowth's book in 1762. Articles in Wikipedia are not always flawless. So I've improved this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative#Litotes) and I think the community has approved.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple negation has long been a feature of English. It continues to be so in nonstandard dialects, but is no longer allowed in Standard English. It isn’t a case of one negative cancelling another. Rather, the greater the number of negatives, the greater the force of the negation. If you think it’s illogical, try telling that to the French, whose standard form of the language features the two negatives *ne* and *pas* used together.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Just correct me if I am wrong. We can't have "nothing" in negative sentence. "Anything" is much suitable.Am I right?

Comment: @Bhushan Firake. If you're thinking of a sentence like _I don't know nothing_, then that is not permissible in Standard English. It will, however, be found in other dialects.

Comment: @BhushanFirake actually you can't have *nothing* in a *positive* sentence. *Nothing* in itself is negative, so it is found only in negative sentences by definition. "I have nothing." "He did nothing."