# Analysing "Ain't got no use for no coal company"

Tags: american-english, syntactic-analysis, conversational-deletion

I'm writing my thesis and I have a problem analysing this sentence:

> **"Ain't got no use for no coal company"** (Grisham, 2014: 157).

I know there's no subject - is it therefore an ellipsis? I don't think so... What is the noun that is missing? If a context would help, here it is:

> "Any idea what the land is worth?"
>
> Mrs. Crump crunched her dentures and said, "A lot more than anybody
>   knows. You see, the coal company came out last year and tried to buy
>   the land, been trying for some time, but I ran 'em off again. Ain't
>   selling to no coal company, no ma'am. They're blasting away not far
>   from my land, taking down Cat Mountain, and it's a real shame. **Ain't
>   got no use for no coal company**."

Carter and McCarthy (2006) provided me with terms such as multiple negation and *ain't* as a negative contraction

Comment: Yes, ellipsis. I ain't selling to no coal company...I ain't got no use for no coal company.  (I have no intention of selling my land to a coal company. I want to have nothing to do with a coal company.)

Comment: @Tim Romano: Erm... I'll take that as a no, then. Or should that be a *no, No, No! **NO!***

Comment: It’s vernacular for, “[I] haven’t got any use for a coal company.”.

Comment: What is your thesis on?

Comment: Doesn't the previous example make it clear ('... the coal company came out last year and tried to buy the land, been trying for some time, but I ran 'em off again. Ain't selling to no coal company, no ma'am. ')? Dropping the subject like this is an example of _conversational deletion_ (qv).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Mrs Crump ain't never had no money, and she don't want none of their money, and she ain't paid no coal company no nevermind.

Comment: my thesis deals with the application of contemporary literature in teaching English - focusing on communicative approach and developing learners' vocabulary, grammar and culture

Comment: [*"Ain't Got No, I Got Life - Nina Simone"*](https://youtu.be/L5jI9I03q8E) -  "Ain't got no X" = "I haven't got any X"

Answer (score 5):

- *Ain't got no use for no coal company*

This sentence has been done several things to.

The first thing is removing the subject *"I"* by [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

The second thing is using idiomatic *got* to mean *have*.

The third thing is using *ain't* (instead of *haven't*) as a negative of *got*  in this sense.
(actually, that's two things - *ain't* is dialectal, and *be* is the wrong auxiliary verb anyway)

The fourth thing is applying [Negative Concord](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113582/15299) instead of Negative Polarity.
That means using extra, non-cancellable negatives to emphasize negation, instead of [NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) like *any*.

Many dialects of American English, including AAVE, use *ain't* with *got*, and use negative concord for emphasis. So it's grammatical, but it's not standard. It's local, and therefore more heartfelt.

Comment: *This sentence has been done several things to.*  Was that an attempt at some sort of vernacular?

Comment: Merely treating a VP with an object and a preposition as a transitive V undergoing Passive.

Comment: People have been hanged for less (assuming 'Sherlock' is a reality series).

Comment: The noun phrase _reality series_ is a wonderful oxymoron I hadn't considered before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "no use for no coal company" is a classic example of a double negative resulting from a attempt to be emphatic.

The subject is an implied "I", and a more grammatical version would be, "I haven't any use for the coal company.", since only a single coal company has been showing interest in her land. A more emphatic and general version, reflecting her disdain for coal mining in general would be "I haven't any use for any coal company".

Well, actually it might be considered grammatical, since it's actually a triple negative, rather than a double negative, and so the negative overall meaning is preserved.