# "I ain't never seen" vs "I ain't seen" which one is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, formality, negative-concord

As far as i know we do not need to add "never" because ain't is already have a negative meaning.

Comment: Alao [Correct interpretation of a double negative in American pop culture](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353278/correct-interpretation-of-a-double-negative-in-american-pop-culture-i-e-i-a/353292#353292)/). Neither is standard English; the double negative doesn't really compound this issue.

Comment: "I ain't never seen nobody do nothin' like that" is perfectly legit in this argot.

Comment: It's not necessary to add _never_, but it's a way to increase the emphasis.