# Afro American specific slang

Tags: slang, african-american-vernacular-english

I'm from South America and I've been fluent (at least in my opinion) in English for several years as of now. With this in mind it has really called my attention lately that I've heard Afro-American people say, for example,

"I don't like *no* cats" instead of "I don't like cats". With double negation.

And the other one is, for example,

"Look at *them* kids" instead of "Look at *the* kids". With *them* instead of *the*.

It is not really confusing tbh but I'm just curious about why this happens?

Comment: It's not particularly AAVE. What all these features (double negatives, ***them*** instead of ***those***, discarding certain "content-free" verbs, etc.) have in common is they *explicitly* ignore "standard, mainstream" syntax. This usually leads to *simpler* syntax (or in the case of double negatives, greater *emphasis*). People everywhere have a natural tendency to do this - it's just that outside of "established" dialects like AAVE, people are likely to have been trained since childhood to avoid such "syntactically incorrect" usages.

Comment: The Rolling Stones: *I can't get no satisfaction* is vernacular **British English**. So is Pink Floyd's *Teacher, leave them kids alone*.

Comment: Like an explanation for why different dialects exist at all? An explanation of how these features came to be found in AAVE? We do already have questions about these features: [Origin and correctness of “ain’t no”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113541/191178) and [Could "them" mean "those"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/150674/191178) — note that neither of these is specific to AAVE.

Comment: “*However, we hear double and triple negatives spoken in some regional dialects of English. This is common when people from the same region are speaking with one another. Double negatives like this are not acceptable in formal situations or in writing.*” Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: I'd use '... I've been fluent (at least in my opinion) in English for several years now.'

Comment: "I don't like no cats" does not reduce to "I don't like cats" in meaning, but to "I don't like **any** cats."

Comment: @WeatherVane, I wouldn't consider it obvious to outsiders that lyrics by those bands represent British usage. Both of them (especially the Stones) produced a lot of material imitating African American artists.

Comment: I absolutely love that. I will sometimes use these. I'm a learner but I believe knowing how to use this and when shows a greater proficiency and knowledge of the English language. Also, I'm quite educated.

Answer (score -4):

Those two particular practices are common in the speech of the lesser educated in North America, and not only the Afro-American section of this social stratum;  moreover the double negation equivalent to a single negation is not at all uncommon in the English of the literate individuals whose occupation consist in providing entertainment to the public, both in North America and the UK; it is remarkable that Bob Dylan, for instance, a now Nobel prize of literature, uses it in his songs ([You Ain’t Goin’ Nowhere (1967)](https://jcodybobdylanwords.com/2019/07/09/you-aint-goin-nowhere-1967/)); as for the UK, one might refer to the *Rolling Stones*, who show no less scruples in using this grammar ("[I can't get no satisfaction](https://www.quora.com/Does-it-bring-any-thoughts-to-you-to-realize-the-famous-Rolling-Stones-line-I-cant-get-no-satisfaction-is-a-double-negative-What-thoughts-does-it-bring)"). It is then clear, that, however criticized those practices might be on both sides of the Atlantic, they remain deeply ingrained in the culture, and one should not be surprised to realize that they persist.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148693/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-afro-american-specific-slang); please do not continue the discussion here.