# Is this phrase past tense or present tense?

Tags: tenses, have-got, aint

The following phrase

> I ain't got no money

Is it meant to be used for a past action (*I didn't get no money*) or is it used to mean (*I don't get no money right now*)?

What confuses me is the usage of *got* (past tense of *get*). I understand that *ain't* can be used ad a substitution of *am not*, *did not*, *do not*, *is/are not*, etc.

Comment: Here *ain't* is used to mean *have not*.

Comment: Present. ~"I do not have any money." The double negative is used here as an intensifier.

Comment: It's present tense, and _I ain't got_ is an idiom with a special meaning: 'I don't have'. Past tense would be _I didn't have no money_; _(ain't) got_ in the sense of '(don't) have' only works in the present tense.

Comment: As others have noted, *got* is for possession, *gotten* is for reception. *I ain't gotten no visits from the sheriff all month* or *I ain't gotten any help since the accident*  vs. *I ain't got no ride no more* or *I ain't got six bits to my name*.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that *ain't* can mean 'did not'? The closest  usage to that would be *I ain't done that*, where *ain't* = 'have not'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause is in the present tense.

Although *got* is a past form of *get,* it is also

> used for saying "have" in informal speech
>       *What you got there?
>
>       You got to be careful what you say to him.*

--http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/got_1

It means: *I have no money.*

Answer (score 1):

"I ain't got no money" means "I don't have any money." It's spoken slang usage. You can check urbandictionary.com for explanation (type in "ain't got no"). Or this link ["I ain't got no money"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47527/i-aint-got-no-money)
for longer explanation.

Also, the verb *got* here means "have." So the idea is that you don't have money, not that you are not getting money.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cmcf and I will add that in the UK "ain't" should really be used only for the present of the verbs "to be" and "to have" (negative, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence "ain't" stands for "haven't", so your sentence is

- I haven't got no money.

Grammatically "have got/ haven't got" is present perfect. But in BrE "have got" serves as a paraphrase for to have in the sense of to possess/to own.

If you have got a letter, the consequence is that you have a letter. That's the way how a grammatical perfect can develop the sense of a present tense.

Why a paraphrase for to have? In most cases " have" is shortened to 've. That is one sound, /v/. You can't stress it. Compare:

- 1 Yes, I've a car, - 2 Yes, I've got a car.

In 2 you can give weight to the word got. In 1 you can't give weight to /v/.